# How to post back the html page source of the current page that is loaded(no refresh)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

The subject says it all but i'll further explain. If i am on a page that has a button on it, how can i wire up the button to capture the page source and send it back to the controller for storing it? I can store it as byte array or any file type. I can't find any solutions for posting back the page source of the current page. All the examples i have found use something like WebClient which you supply a url for it to load up and then capture the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a button with id="btn" here is the sample:

```
<script>
$('#btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('html').html(),
        url: 'exmaplesite.com/postaction',
        success: function () {
            alert('success');

        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: in this way you can send the inner html of the html tag of the page and in the controller save it

Comment: Thank you, it's ultimately for a screenshot of the page at a specific state..this will do what i need!! Thanks :D

Comment: you're welcome. if you need further help, contact me